# three.js ".getWorldPosition() target is now required" error message

Tags: three.js

i have been using this to find all of the objects in the line of sight of my camera.

```
var raycaster;
raycaster.set( camera.getWorldPosition(), camera.getWorldDirection() );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
```

it works, but i am seeing these errors in the console.

```
THREE.Object3D: .getWorldPosition() target is now required
THREE.Camera: .getWorldDirection() target is now required
```

i tried creating a vector for this purpose.

```
var rayvector = new THREE.Vector3();
raycaster.set(camera.getWorldPosition(rayvector), camera.getWorldDirection(rayvector));
```

the warnings have gone away now, but raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children) is now returning an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

thanks to bai for helping me with this. :)

my problem was i was using the same vector for both position and direction. when i used two separate vectors it worked.

```
var cameraPostion = new THREE.Vector3();
var cameraDirection = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.getWorldPosition(cameraPostion);
camera.getWorldDirection(cameraDirection);
raycaster.set( cameraPostion, cameraDirection );
```